# Is it correct to say that gravitational force is dependent on intervening medium?

Tags: gravity

Please help me I am little bit confused with regard to the following example:

If we drop a ball and a feather then I think the ball will fall faster and reach the ground first.
But if we remove the air and create a vacuum then they will fall at the same rate and reach the ground at the same time.

Comment: It depends on the accuracy you want. The more massive object should fall faster because the Earth should move towards it a little more than in the case of the feather, according to their center of mass reference frame.

Answer (score 1):

No, gravity does not depend on the medium. In Newtonian physics, gravity is related to mass. In relativistic physics, the curvature of space-time is what we perceive as gravity.

If you drop a ball and a feather then the acceleration due to gravity is the same for both. The difference is that the retardation from air resistance is much greater for the feather than for the ball. Basically, that the ball lands first when dropped in air is because the sum of the forces acting on the ball is different than the sum of the forces acting on the feather.

This experiment was done during the [Apollo 15 moon mission by dropping a hammer and a feather](https://youtu.be/ZVfhztmK9zI).

Comment: But I have asked about another thing that does the gravity depend upon the intervening medium.

Comment: No, it does not. I have edited my answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration of an object due to gravity is independent of the medium. The gravitational force exerted on an object is also independent of the medium. What is not independent of the medium is the *net force* acting on an object when there is an intervening medium, such as air, causing an upward force on the object. The acceleration of the object will then be

$$a=\frac{mg-F_{D}}{m}$$

where $F_D$ is the upward drag force on the object and $mg$ is the downward force of gravity on the object.

Since the the mass of the feather is much less than the ball, an upward drag force will quickly equal the gravitational force on the feather so that it will reach its terminal velocity (when $a=0$) well before the ball, so the ball will reach the ground first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then it depend upon intervening medium(air in this case) as if there is no air both feather and ball fall at the same time.May be I have misunderstood you

Comment: @AnweshPanda Yes, look at my equation for $a$. If there is no intervening medium then the drag force $F_{D}=0$ and $a=g$ regardless of the value of $m$ be it the feather or the ball. They would both fall with the same acceleration $g$ which means they will both go the same distance for same amount of time.

Comment: @Anwesh Panda I think you are confusing the difference between the affect of the intervening medium on the net force on the object and the affect on the gravitational force. As I said in my answer it only affects the net force not the gravitational force